# Posting facebook api not as page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've made facebook app, got appID and secret, and I am trying to post to a page as the page. I've granted the app permission.

But when I'm posting, new post creates "as user", not as page.

My code:

```
require '../lib/fb/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('APP_ID','SECRET');

$session = new FacebookSession('ACCESS_TOKEN');


try {
  $response = (new FacebookRequest(
            $session, 'POST', '/1429642034012499/feed', array(
                'message'       => 'test',
                'link'          => 'http://mylink',
            )
        ))->execute()->getGraphObject();

        print_r($response);
} catch (FacebookRequestException $e) {
   echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
        echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

} catch (\Exception $e) {

}
```

[Page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Worldservice-Group/1429642034012499?ref=hl) to view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Answer is for C#, using the .NET Facebook API Library. But Logic should be same in PHP.

You have to get the Page Access Token:

Go Here: developers.facebook.com/tools/

Then Go to this Link:

[image]

Then Click on: "`Get Access Token`"

Then Add these Permissions:

[image]

Then Copy New access Token:

[image]

Now in C# Class I do (This is the POST A Comment as Page):

```
var userClient = new FacebookClient("THE NEW ACCESS TOKEN YOU JUST GENERATED");

dynamic accountInfo = userClient.Get("USER_ID" + "/accounts"); 

//USER_ID Should be Digits, this is the UserID when you do: facebook.com/USERID it should come up with the Admin Profile

var pageAccessToken = accountInfo.data[0].access_token;

var pageClient = new FacebookClient(pageAccessToken);

dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.message = model.Message;

dynamic pageResult = pageClient.Post(string.Format("{0}/comments",), parameters);
```